# Sed is not working with sh -c in remote server

Tags: bash, sed, sh

I have a requirement where I need to replace line feed characters appearing as part of a data field in a CSV files. Fortunately all the unnecessary linefeeds are followed by an '_' character. So I decided to used sed to preprocess the file. The following command in sed works if run it interactively.

```
sed -i -e ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n_/_/g' file
```

But in server, the command will get executed with `sh -c "<command>"`

To test it in local, I ran the same command with sh and it is not working. The command looks as follows.

```
sh -c "sed -i -e ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n_/_/g' file"
```

Not sure what I'm missing. Please help.

Comment: `$` has a special meaning between doublequotes, you're losing `$!` to expansion

Comment: probably something not escaped/quoted correctly or different sed running on server?

Comment: might be interesting to issue `set -vx` prior to running the `sh -c ...` command, objective being to see how the content between the double quotes is being processed; I'm guessing (at a minimum) the `$!ba` is being processed as some sort of variable (one possible solution would be to escape the `$`, eg, `...:a;N;\$!ba;...`)

Comment: Thanks @markp-fuso.. Escaping $ worked. :)

Answer (score 2):

Between double-quotes, [`$!` expands to the PID of most recent background command (or the empty string if there is not one)](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_02). Pass sed script as a positional parameter to sh to avoid dealing with quotation issues/escaping every special character:

```
sh -c 'sed -i -e "$1" file' _ ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n_/_/g'
```

See also: [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash)

Comment: Thanks @oguz_ismail.. But I don't have control over the quotes in server side. I can only mention the command.. The server automatically adds sh -c to the command with double quotes by default around it. Unfortunately even escaping $ is working only in local and not working in server.